# Programming: find the total possible combinations of three variables?

Tags: combinatorics

I have three variables in a programming function, and a 4th variable depends on these. I have to test the dependent variable against all combinations of the three variables:

- Var A: 2 possible values
- Var B: 3 possible values
- Var C: 5 possible values

The order of the three variables is not important. How can I find the number of possible combinations of these three variables, so that I know how many tests would need to be written?

**Note:**
I have asked a [further question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501998/how-do-you-draw-visualize-a-combination-table) regarding this:

> Now I know that there are 30 combinations of these three variables
>   (2x3x5), but how do I draw this in table form?
>
> If each variable was binary, I could draw a truth table: 000, 001, 010
>   etc. But is there an equivalent system for the combination I have
>   detailed here?

Thanks

Brian

Comment: Brian already answered, but from a programming standpoint, are you talking about unit testing your function or a 30 case switch statement.  If you're talking about a 30 case switch statement, you might consider refactoring that function as it'll likely be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I wanted to know the combinations for unit testing purposes.. .good point though:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of the $2$ possible values of $A$ there are $3$ possible values of $B$; that makes $2\cdot 3=6$ possible combinations, as you can see by setting up a $2\times 3$ grid showing all $6$ combinations.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\\ \hline
&b_1&b_2&b_3\\ \hline
a_1&(a_1,b_1)&(a_1,b_2)&(a_1,b_3)\\ \hline
a_2&(a_2,b_1)&(a_2,b_2)&(a_2,b_3)\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Each of these $6$ combinations can in turn be combined with any of the $5$ possible values of $C$, so the same reasoning gives you a total of $6\cdot5=30$ combinations.

The general principle, sometimes called the *multiplication* or *Chinese menu* principle, is that if you have a sequence of $n$ choices to be made, and the $k$-th choice can be make in $m_k$ ways independently of the other choices, then the total number of ways to make the combined choice is $$m_1m_2m_3\dots m_n\;,$$ the product of the numbers of ways to make the individual choices.

Comment: Thanks, the detailed explanation is appreciated.... it seems intuitive, but I didnt want to rely on my intuitions alone:-)

Comment: I have asked a question on a similar vein... regarding how to draw a table for the combinations described above. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501998/how-do-you-draw-visualize-a-combination-table